# Thymeleaf gets all images from folders

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

is it possible to gets all images from folders?

I mean I've images structure like this

```
folder1 ---
   ---image1.jpg
   ---image2.jpg
   ---image3.jpg

folder2 ---
   ---image1.jpg
   ---image2.jpg
```

how can I display all images in html?

@edit

only my tries:

```
<p th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, 5)}">
        <img th:src="@{/folder/001/0.jpg}"/>
    </p>
```

Comment: Where's your code? What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in to Thymeleaf to read a folder and get a list of files in it. If you're trying to build something dynamically (which I'm not sure from your question if that's what you're trying to do), then you'd need to read it in your controller (whatever Java code is putting together the context variable map or model that you're sending to Thymeleaf).

If you're just trying to do a static list of five numbered images, like your example code, then you need to do concatenation of your "each" variable inside an expression to generate your image URL, like this:

```
<p th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, 5)}">
    <img th:src="@{${'/folder/001/' + i + '.jpg'}}"/>
</p>
```

That will generate the following HTML:

```
<p>
    <img src="/context/folder/001/1.jpg" />
</p>
<p>
    <img src="/context/folder/001/2.jpg" />
</p>
<p>
    <img src="/context/folder/001/3.jpg" />
</p>
<p>
    <img src="/context/folder/001/4.jpg" />
</p>
<p>
    <img src="/context/folder/001/5.jpg" />
</p>
```

There are more examples of creating [Link URLs in the documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls). These show how you can use an expression to construct the base URL or to construct any query arguments (though usually you don't use query arguments when loading images).